# How to Append to a Field in MongoDB C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, nosql

I can't seem to find this answer anywhere about Appending to a field.

In SQL I could do something like this: UPDATE Table1 SET Field1 = Field1 + ' xxx' WHERE Field2=1

But in Mongo, I can't see how I can appennd/concat using the Update query.

If I have a document as such

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("581f06f40ead9db2dc50a13f"),
    "userid" : "5812f6940ead9e85c0f8a66a",
    "username" : "Hayden Mcwilliam",
    "description" : "Loving life. Ping me.",
    "createddate" : ISODate("2016-11-06T10:33:24.819Z")
}
```

And I want to append the text "Call me now" to the end of the "description" field, how can I do that with MongoDB using the C# driver.

I can get the value with a find query and then concat it to a string var and then do the update. But I thought there must be an easier way.

Thanks in advance Stackerrrrrs!

Comment: Kevin, that is updating specific fields. Question is about appending to the field.

Comment: There is **no such thing** as **appending to a field**. You can only read the document and then write the result after appending to the existing property value in code. Also the "nosql" tag was removed for a reason. As again "no such thing as nosql". You are using "MongoDB", which does not share syntax with anything else.